# How to connect to dom0 console from a trusted domU?

Tags: xen

Is there a way to connect from a trusted domU to dom0 via console?

I'd imagine I need to install some Xen tooling to do this; but, which tools?  And, is there some permissions/firewall I need to delegate to allow a trusted VM to connect dom0?

I am avoiding network/sshd for numerous reasons.

Currently I am using a RPi connected to the serial console port; but, I'd like to get rid of the RPi and connect to one of the trusted domUs I have, and then console from there.

Comment: You could ssh to the raspberry pi, or you could use your IPMI serial over lan functionality.

Comment: Yes, I am currently ssh'ing into the RPi - but want to avoid this. Motherboard does not have IPMI.

Comment: KVM over IP dongle, then? Or get an enterprise grade server with IPMI.

Comment: This is actually a secure network and we refuse to run anybody's IPMI due to all of the exploits present in them. The RPi is connected to an air-gapped management network with machines that were setup being air-gapped as well to minimize the risk of exploits. Thanks for the suggestions; however, we aren't looking for alternatives other than the OP question. :)

Comment: Oops! The RPi is just as full of exploits, as it runs a Linux distribution! You can't win either way. Though I'm very surprised that your security doesn't allow IPMI on an air gapped network. The RPi is much more risky. Anyway, and perhaps ironically, security is the reason you can't do what you're proposing at all.